# How do I manage webservices written using Spring WS/Rest?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, tomcat, spring-ws

I am trying to understand how to manage (scale/start/stop/upgrade) webservices written using Spring WS/REST. If you typically deploy a web application on tomcat, you can easily stop it, restart it. If I deploy Spring WS, will they be deployed in similar fashion to webapp? Would they be accessible as individual applications in tomcat (or any WS container) admin page?

Comment: Spring is a framework which runs in a J2EE compliant container, such as Tomcat.  So when you access your Spring WS service, you will be hitting Tomcat.  You can expect all the usual rules to apply here.

Comment: ok, so let's say I have a WebService which is running in a single tomcat server. I expect a lot of load on it, and I need scale vertically - meaning, I need to run a clone of that web service and load balance incoming requests on that single machine, How would I do it?

Comment: You should ask a new question about this.  You are asking about hardware architecture whereas your original question was really about software frameworks.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, you are correct, it is going in a different direction. If you can respond with an answer, I will accept your answer.